# value range in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple code for titanic data:

```
import pandas as pd

def pClassSurvivorDetails(df,pClass):
    print('\nResults for Pclass =', pClass, '\n -------------------- ')
    print("The following did not survive")
    notSurvive = df['Sex'][df['Survived']==0][df['Pclass']==pClass]
    print(notSurvive.value_counts())
    print("The following did survive")
    survive = df['Sex'][df['Survived']==1][df['Pclass']==pClass]
    print(survive.value_counts())

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")
    for value in [1, 2, 3]:
    pClassSurvivorDetails(df,value, )

main()
```

Now I need to do the same result but instead of for value in [1, 2, 3] i need first number =x last number= y and all between should be included ...something like [1:3](but it doesn't work this way). Any ideas please...

Comment: What's wrong with `for i in range(x,y):`?

Comment: it excludes y and I need x,n,y

Comment: `for i in range(x, y + 1):`

Comment: Thanks! perhaps you know how to get partial results? ie. this code give me survive man from each class so how can I use them, for example, to create a chart. Another word how can I extract values for a single year assuming that the x and y are user input ...

Comment: I've added an answer. Note that if I understand your question correctly, most of the code you've posted is irrelevant. Posting less is a quicker way to get a response.

Answer (score 0):

To cycle through all values between two variables in Python, you can use:

```
for i in range(x, y):
```

Or, since it is up to and not including y, you could include y with:

```
for i in range(x, y + 1):
```

To get all values in this range, and then access only one, the simplest way is to store it as a list.

```
my_values = list(range(x, y))
```

And then you can access with indexing, e.g.:

```
my_values[2]
```

Comment: Thank you Josh. That is very helpful but not exactly what I'm looking for. Part of the result of this function is the number of women survived from each class. it was required that user set number of class to be checked and my goal is to create the plt.plot, where points of one line will be these women, survived from each class plt.plot[34C1, 25C2, 33Cn, etc]

Comment: my_values[2] shows only the user input ie Pclass1 but not the result for this class.

Comment: oh, and manually changing [1] to [2] is not an option. it has to iterate: something like-----> if x in range(-1, len(my_values)): 
     x = x+ 1
     my_values[x]  <--------but it still show me what i want to print but how to extract partial data for plt.plot as i mentioned above